# Can't get ToString() to work for IInspectable content of ComboBoxItem for WinUI 3 using C++

Tags: c++, combobox, winui-3

When supplying an IInspectable as content for a ComboBoxItem, you're supposed to be able to provide a display string by using the ToString() function.  But this function is never called and the display is just a blank box.

Custom IInspectable:

```
class ComboboxItem : public winrt::implements<ComboboxItem, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable>
{
public:
    ComboboxItem() : m_text(L"Hello") {}

    hstring Text() { return m_text; }
    void Text(hstring const& value) { m_text = value; }

    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable Value() { return m_value; }
    void Value(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& value) { m_value = value; }

    hstring ToString() cons { return m_text; }    // This is never called

private:
    hstring m_text;
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable m_value;
};
```

Adding to ComboBox:

```
comboxBox.Items().Append(winrt::make<ComboboxItem>());
```

What is the missing "special sauce" to get the string to display in the ComboBox?

Comment: This is not how it works. WinUI3 is not a C++ framework, it's a WinRT (~COM) binary framework with bindings (more or less smart) for every supported language. A `ComboBoxItem` is a `ContentControl`, and the `Content` can be any `IInspectable` reference.  For a string you can wrap it like it `winrt::box_value(L"hello")`. It could work with WinRT's `IStringable` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windows.foundation/nn-windows-foundation-istringable) but WinUI3 doesn't seem to use it.

Comment: As @SimonMourier said, you need to set your *ComboboxItem* 's [Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.content?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4) to `winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable`. For example, see https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2FWindowsAppSDK-Samples%20box_value&type=code. It's enough to extend `ComboBoxItem`.

Answer (score 0):

I implement in C# because It's the only way I can make it work.

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App2CSharp
{
    internal class MyComboBoxItem : ComboBoxItem
    {
        public MyComboBoxItem()
        {
            Content = "TEST";
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" Header="Colors" PlaceholderText="Pick a color" Width="200">
            <x:String>Blue</x:String>
            <x:String>Green</x:String>
            <x:String>Red</x:String>
            <x:String>Yellow</x:String>
            <ComboBoxItem>Gray</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
```

And

```
ComboBoxItem c = new MyComboBoxItem();
MyComboBox.Items.Add(c);
```

[image]

Complete C++ part.

```
struct MyComboBoxItem : winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::ComboBoxItem
{
    MyComboBoxItem() noexcept 
    {
        Content(box_value(L"TEST2"));
    }
};
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ColorCombo" Header="Colors" PlaceholderText="Pick a color" Width="200">
    <x:String>Blue</x:String>
    <x:String>Green</x:String>
    <x:String>Red</x:String>
    <x:String>Yellow</x:String>
    <ComboBoxItem>Gray</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

And

```
ColorCombo().Items().Append(box_value(L"TEST"));
MyComboBoxItem c{};
ColorCombo().Items().Append(c);
```

Update:
The [Object.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0) Method works for me.

```
    public class MyComboBoxItem
    {
        public MyComboBoxItem()
        {
            //Content = "TEST";
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ("G");
        }

        //string IStringable.ToString()
        //{
        //    return "New ToString in NewClass";
        //}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for posting such a detailed example.  In our situation, we are looking to add additional (non-displayed) info with each item.  How would you go about adding an additional member variable to `MyComboBoxItem` that can be accessed in the selection changed event?

Comment: [The ComboBoxItem class provides the container for items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.comboboxitem?view=winrt-22621). [You of course can access it in the selection changed event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MQpc.png).

Comment: [ItemsControl.Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.items?view=winrt-22621) property is the collection used to generate the content of the control. It just collects what you put in. The item in the selection changed event is the item you put in the `Items`. @Stevo

Comment: Seen [your GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/8981), finally [IPropertyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windows.foundation/nn-windows-foundation-ipropertyvalue) also works.

Comment: Although [Data template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/item-containers-templates#data-template) says, *By default, a data item is displayed in the list view as the string representation of the data object it's bound to. If you show the 'NamedColors' data in a list view without telling the list view how it should look, it just shows whatever the **ToString** method returns, like this.*